# Error: need ‘typename’ before iterator

Tags: c++

Hey guys i have this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<vector>

template<class T>
class ListLib {
public:
    ListLib(std::list<T>& listItem) {
        *listT = listItem;
    }

    std::vector<T> convertToVector() {
        std::vector<T> result;
        std::list<T>::iterator itList;

        for (itList = *listT->begin(); itList != *listT->end(); itList++)
            result->(*itList);

        std::vector<T>::iterator itVec;
        for (itVec = result.begin(); itVec != result.end())
            std::cout << *itVec << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::list<T> *listT;
};

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> sampleList;
    std::vector<std::string> sampleVector;
    sampleList.push_back("3");
    sampleList.push_back("4");
    sampleList.push_back("5");
    sampleList.push_back("6");

    ListLib<std::string> listLib(sampleList);
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

And i tried to resolve many errors i got with this, but led to no good!I made a function that does same thing as libary im making now with a class. i need help! Here is error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp: In member function ‘std::vector<T> ListLib<T>::convertToVector()’:                                                                                                                 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:15:3: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<T>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<T>’ is a dependent scope                                                                            
   std::list<T>::iterator itList;                                                                                    
   ^                                                                                                                 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:15:26: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘itList’                     
   std::list<T>::iterator itList;                                                                                    
                          ^                                                                                          
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:17:8: error: ‘itList’ was not declared in this scope           
   for (itList = *listT->begin(); itList != *listT->end(); itList++)                                                 
        ^                                                                                                            
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:18:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token         
    result->(*itList);                                                                                               
            ^                                                                                                        
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:20:3: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<T>::iterator’ because ‘std::vector<T>’ is a dependent scope                                                                        
   std::vector<T>::iterator itVec;                                                                                   
   ^                                                                                                                 
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:20:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘itVec’                      
   std::vector<T>::iterator itVec;                                                                                   
                            ^                                                                                        
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:21:8: error: ‘itVec’ was not declared in this scope            
   for (itVec = result.begin(); itVec != result.end())                                                               
        ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/c++/CustomLibaries/listLib.cpp:21:53: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
   for (itVec = result.begin(); itVec != result.end())
                                                     ^
```

Comment: You are missing semi collens all over the place.... and ever where it says you need a `typename` before it (like `std::vector<T>::iterator`) change it to `typename std::vector<T>::iterator`

Comment: Hmm @DarthRubik ! semi collens? xD .. Anways why do i need typename? What does it do?

Comment: What part of "need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<T>::iterator’" you couldn't understand?

Comment: The error message is literal enough. So literal that you even have a keyword to ask Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing many semicolons, and you also need the keyword `typename` before all the itterators.. This fixes all the issues you have:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<vector>

template<class T>
class ListLib {
public:
    ListLib(std::list<T>& listItem) {
        *listT = listItem;
    }

    std::vector<T> convertToVector() {
        std::vector<T> result;
        typename std::list<T>::iterator itList;

        for (itList = *listT->begin(); itList != *listT->end(); itList++)
                result.push_back(*itList);

        typename std::vector<T>::iterator itVec;
        for (itVec = result.begin(); itVec != result.end(); itVec++)
            std::cout << *itVec << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::list<T> *listT;
};

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> sampleList;
    std::vector<std::string> sampleVector;
    sampleList.push_back("3");
    sampleList.push_back("4");
    sampleList.push_back("5");
    sampleList.push_back("6");

    ListLib<std::string> listLib(sampleList);
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

/*template<class T>
void convertListToVector(std::list<T> *listItem, std::vector<T> *vectorConvert) {
std::list<T>::iterator it;
for (it = *listItem->begin(); it != *listItem->end(); it++)
*vectorConvert->push_back(*it);
}*/
```

Working <kbd>["`C++ Fiddle`"](http://cpp.sh/6dmyy)</kbd>